# What should be the `aria-role` of an accordion? During accessibility check, my accordions are read as buttons, which may confuse the user

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, roles, wai-aria

I have a webpage and I have managed to keep few accordions in it as well. Since I have given `"role"="button"` on accordions, my accordions are read as 'button' during accessibility testing.

What should be the aria-parameter values if I wanted my accordions to be read as accordions itself, not buttons?

Can someone give an insight on it? Also, it would be great if anyone can share the accessibility testing standards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the average user, a button is a thing you activate to make something happen while an accordion is a musical instrument. The roles you have already are fine.

There is no aria role to describe something as an accordion.

The latest W3C
WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices note includes a [section about accordions](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion) which uses buttons which is accompanied by [a complete example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/accordion/accordion.html).

Comment: Since we are targetting a customer with a disability at this point, reading an accordian as a button is something conveying a wrong message to them, isn't it ? What would be the ideal way to handle this scenario ? Do you have any idea on it ?

Comment: @ArunRamachandran — It isn't conveying an accordion as a button. It is conveying a button (which makes some content visible) as a button.

Comment: It's highly doubtful that any customer will know what an "accordion" pattern is, so having some kind of label, whether visible or just for screen readers, that says the thing is an accordion will not help.  A custom probably **is** familiar with selecting something and having it cause something else to appear or hide (expand or collapse).  That's the information you should expose and is done with `aria-expanded` as mentioned in the accordion authoring practice reference that @Quentin posted.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

- Use `dl` element with `role="presentation"` attribute.
- Use `dt` element with `role="heading"` for headings of accordion.
- Put button inside `dt` or heading so it will be implicitly focusable with tab order
- give button `aria-expanded' attribute and set it to true when accordion panel is expanded otherwise set to false.
- Put data in `dd` element

[Here you can find more information with example in w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/accordion/accordion.html)

Comment: *For accordion widget role is role="presentation".* — Err, no, not really. That means "Ignore the normal semantics of this element, it is being used only for presentation". It doesn't add the meaning "This is an accordian".

Comment: @Quentin That was based on [w3c best practice](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/accordion/accordion.html), He can use `aria-label="accordion some other label"`, and bootstrap is using `role='tablist', There is no specific `role` for accordion

Comment: I know where you got the information from. I was criticising your explanation of it. Using an `aria-label` to describe something as an accordion (which is industry jargon) is a terrible idea unless the website is targetted at UX professionals. Using `aria-label` is a pretty poor idea in this context anyway, it is used when there is no visible label (e.g. when you have a button described only with an icon). I can't think of any situation where it would be appropriate to use on an accordion.

Comment: @Quentin. Yes you are right. my point was there is no aria-role to describe an accordion

Comment: Here's the new location for the WC3/WAI example: [https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen examples where the `tablist` role is used for an accordion widget --  which seems very reasonable (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#tablist).

Anyway, WAI does not do that in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion. Instead they demand that the controls to show/hide the panels are buttons (ideally with `<button>`s and without explicit roles) and that their interaction with the panels is described with `aria-expanded`, `aria-controls` and (depending on implementation) `aria-disabled`. The panel might be a `region` if you deem the content important enough. Finally, don't forget to make the accordion accessible by keyboard.

Comment: The WAI accordion example has move to a new location: [https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

ARIA roles are not used extensively in accordions. The one role attribute you should use is role="region". Apply this to the div element that is expandable, for accordions that have 6 or fewer panels.

Here is a simple example for an FAQ accordion with one question and answer, which you can repeat for additional questions and answers.

```
<h3>Question
  <button type="button">
    Question
  </button>
</h3>
<div role="region">
  <p>Answer</p>
</div>
```

There are additional attributes you can add that would be beneficial for screen readers. See the [W3 website](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/accordion/accordion.html) for additional guidance.

Comment: You should label the region. Also you should use a native element like section. `<section title="Question">` completely avoids Aria. Usually I prefer aria-labelledby though